# How to fix double permission popup in MAUI ios web view

Tags: webview, permissions, maui

I have a Maui App and i'm trying to open my streaming website inside the WebView.

But everytime i open my streaming website inside Maui WebView ,the website is asking for camera permission "so annoying for the user" (even if the user already granted camera access to my app in the first time i installed it).

My question ,is there any way to disable the permission prompt inside the WebView website and make the website uses the given permission of the app itself.

did anyone face a similar problem ?

thanks for your help.

Comment: What WebView is this? Are we supposed to guess what you are doing?

Comment: i'm asking for .Net Maui WebView ( "i want to stop asking for camera permission by the website inside the WebView everytime i open the app","instead i want my WebView to ask for the camera permission just for one time")

Comment: My point is why does your Webview need Camera permission, without context the question is vague at best

Comment: I modified the question FreakyAli (thanks for your remark)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that you are using `getUserMedia()` to get camera. You can set the `WKUIDelegate` for the webview in iOS.

```
public class CustomWebViewDelegate :WKUIDelegate
       {
         [Export("webView:requestMediaCapturePermissionForOrigin:initiatedByFrame:type:decisionHandler:")]
        public override void RequestMediaCapturePermission(WKWebView webView, WKSecurityOrigin origin, WKFrameInfo frame, WKMediaCaptureType type,Action<WKPermissionDecision> decisionHandler)
        {
            decisionHandler(WKPermissionDecision.Grant);//Missing this line will result in a blank camera screen
            base.RequestMediaCapturePermission(webView, origin, frame, type, decisionHandler);
        }
    }
```

And then set the delegate in OnElementChanged method in your WKWebviewRenderer:

```
if (e.NewElement != null)
{
       UIDelegate = new CustomWebViewDelegate();

}
```

Reference links:

Please watch the clip around 12:30 in this Apple's video:[Explore WKWebView additions - WWDC21 - Videos - Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10032/).

[Using Custom Renderers in .NET MAUI](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/wiki/Using-Custom-Renderers-in-.NET-MAUI)

[Use custom renderers in .NET MAUI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/migration/custom-renderers?view=net-maui-7.0)

**Update:**

```
      public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp() 
      {
            var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
            builder
                  .UseMauiApp<App>()
                  .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
                  {
                        fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
                        fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
                  })

        .ConfigureMauiHandlers(handlers =>

        {

            handlers.AddHandler(typeof(HybridWebView), typeof(HybridWebViewHandler));

        });
        ;

        Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.WebViewHandler.Mapper.AppendToMapping("custom",(handler, view) =>
        {
            handler.PlatformView.UIDelegate = new CustomWebViewDelegate();
        }
        );


        return builder.Build();
    }


#if IOS
    public class CustomWebViewDelegate : WKUIDelegate

    {

        [Export("webView:requestMediaCapturePermissionForOrigin:initiatedByFrame:type:decisionHandler:")]

        public override void RequestMediaCapturePermission(WKWebView webView, WKSecurityOrigin origin, WKFrameInfo frame, WKMediaCaptureType type, Action<WKPermissionDecision> decisionHandler)

        {
            decisionHandler(WKPermissionDecision.Grant);//Missing this line will result in a blank camera screen

            base.RequestMediaCapturePermission(webView, origin, frame, type, decisionHandler);

        }

    }
#endif
```

Comment: Thank you Alexandar May ,I'm using getUserMedia in my website and didn't know how to add a custom UIDelegate on Maui to pass the permission popup (https://github.com/dotnet/maui/wiki/Using-Custom-Renderers-in-.NET-MAUI worked for me)

Comment: appreciate your help

Comment: Thanks for the update, you can add it at any where, just make sure it's been executed before loading the webview. I added it in `MauiProgram.cs` , you can refer to it.

Comment: I follow the instruction given above with a slight modification to allow me to set the UserAgent. But the RequestMediaCapturePermission is not called at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls;
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls.PlatformConfiguration;
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific;

...

var webView = new WebView
{
    Source = "https://example.com"
};

webView.On<iOS>().SetAllowsInlineMediaPlayback(true);
webView.On<iOS>().SetPrefersEphemeralWebBrowserSession(true);

// only request permissions when the user interacts with the web view
webView.On<iOS>().SetShouldPromptForPermission(false);

Content = webView;
```

Comment: thanks for your answer HelmBurger , i tried your solution but the extension methos after webView.On<iOS>().... are not exist in Maui (i'm using maui .net 7 and visual studio 17.5.0)